# Error retrieving data from database at 000webhost using c# program

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I try to access mysql database using php and c#. I write the code as below, and "Root element is missing" error is occured. I just want to ask why? and is the code will work?

C# Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.minzhe-chengyee.comule.com/vieworder.php");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader input = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            DataSet dsTest = new DataSet();
            dsTest.ReadXml(input);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTest.Tables[0];
        }
```

PHP Script

```
 <?php

$con=mysql_connect('mysql17.000webhost.com','a2634311_eee2110','fypeee2110');
 mysql_select_db("a2634311_fyp",$con);


 $table=$_POST['table'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];


 mysql_query("select * from ordertable");

?>
```

Comment: what does the response look like?

Comment: the issue isn't the C# program... it is your PHP script which is reading from the database. Based on the code extract, looks like the web response is simply relaying the error reading the DB on the web server.

Comment: it's the PHP script problem.. i changed it dy, it already can work.. thanks